# CSS in Outlook email its not working properly

Tags: html, css, email, responsive-design

I have been working on a project and one of the features is to send an email verification message. I am trying to optimize it especially for the outlook platform. The problem I have been encountering is that the `flex-box` is not working as it should on the mobile app, but on the web app is working just fine. I am using `flex-direction: column` but it displays as `row`. Is there any way to overcome this?

```
*,
*::after,
*::before {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    font-family: 'Fabula Valhalla';
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 16px;
}

body{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}

.background{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #151A29;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.main-container{
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.33);
    width: 80%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 35px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    border-radius: 25px;
}

.image{
    width: 90%;
    border-radius: 25px;
    border: solid 2px #B94E36
}

h1{
    margin-top: 30px;
    font-size: 46px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.text-container{
    margin-top: 30px;
    width: 80%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 22px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    line-height: 24px;
}

.button{
    margin-top: 40px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    background-color: #EBA550;
    border-radius: 25px;
    padding: 15px 50px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `display:flex` has pretty good support across email clients, `flex-direction:row` has not. So in your example, both `flex-direction: column;` and `align-items: center;` would be stripped out from Outlook.com or Outlook on iOS and Android, leaving you with just the defaults that come with `display:flex` (corresponding to `flex-direction:row` and `align-items:stretch`).

I’d recommend using another layout method more compatible with email clients, like `display:inline-block` or tables.

- [Can I email… flex-direction](https://www.caniemail.com/features/css-flex-direction/)
- [Can I email… display:flex](https://www.caniemail.com/features/css-display-flex/)